# Android restore listview selected position

Tags: android, listview

This is very trivial and am sure i am missing something basic here

i have a activity with a listview (populated thru `ArrayAdapter`)

in the adapter I have implemented my onClick listener that launches another activity.

Based on a few suggestion i have save the state of the `getSelectedItemPosition` in the `onSaveInstanceState` which i have overridden

The problem is when i am navigate back to the mainactivity, i am expecting `onRestoreInstanceState` to be called where i can set the setPosition to the position I have stored in `onSaveInstanceState` , but its not called.

So the end results is that when i can come back to the mainactivity the selection is rolled to the first row. which is not a very good user experience.

Comment: please provide some code to understand what u have done till now!!

Comment: @ashish The code is big - however the excerpt of mainactivity methods is as follows: hope this helps 

onSaveInstanceState method 

`{
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
 outState.putInt("selectedPosition",lView.getSelectedItemPosition());
}
`
inside the onRestoreInstanceState the code is 
 
{ `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
  ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
  lView.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedPosition"));

 }`

Comment: Just to clarify, your list view is scrolled to top when you resume the activity or you select a row and when the activity is resumed, that row ins't selected anymore?

Comment: its the first case - the listview is scrolled to the top when the activity is resumed

As suggested by @app i tried getting the `getItemSelectedPosition` but it is coming -1

Could it be becoz i am using an onClick within a ArrayAdapter implementation?

Comment: As far as I know, the list view is showed in the same state when activity is resumed, so you don't have to deal with it. I'm sure that this is not the case, but are you using the list in a fragment?

Comment: my mainactivity contains `<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />`
I am further setting the View thru 

`TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_view, arrayList);`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by saving the `lastItemSelected position` in a int field of your Activity called `lastItemSelected` (remember to update this variabe every time you click on a element of the list)

Save last item

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                lastItemSelected = position;

            }
        });
```

Then on the `onResume()` lifecycle method do:

```
yourListView.setSelection(lastItemSelected)
```

---

`onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstance` etc etc are method used for restore your activity state when it is forcefully terminated by the OS.

Comment: the value of `getSelectedItemPosition` is coming -1

i have been trying various things and usage of `onRestoreInstance' and `onSaveInstanceState` is last thing i tried :(